# How to move a column to the end?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to align column with text to far right side of the window but somehow its not happening.

Tried with `MainAxisAlignment.right` , `CrossAxisAlignment.right` but somehow nothing is working out for me. Below is my Dart code,

```
class MVTHomePage extends StatelessWidget {


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 550,
            width: width,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Lottie.network(
                    'https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/6WfDdm3ooQTEs1L/data.json'),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("Multivariate Testing"),
                    Text('Run experiments to make key flows more effective.'),
                    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Create Experiment')),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I am seeing this in the output

[image: My Output Screenshot]

Comment: you can add `Spacer()`, above the widget you want to put at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are using the `Row` widget,

Add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to it.

So your code should be like this

```
child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // <-- Add this
    children: [
        Lottie.network(
```

When your `Row`'s children are being rendered, by giving it `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, we are essentially telling the `Row` to place its children as far apart from each other as possible.

In the case of 2 children, it means 1 child to the extreme left and other to the extreme right.